# integrate paypal access with ios application

Tags: ios, email, paypal

I have integarated paypal sdk to my ios app. User can login to my app and use "Pay with Paypal" button to pay. But I want merchant to login in my app with his paypal id and want to store his paypal email address in my app database. Please help me to retrive merchant email address. I have searched a lot and found login with paypal access but I am not able to integrate it with my iphone app.

I want to authenticate merchant email address ,whether it is his paypal email Id or its fake. Like we do in facebook while login and we get dictionary in response having email address and other fields

Comment: why store paypal email address, once your transaction is over you get all details

Comment: I am having merchants and users both in my app ,merchant provide services ,and user uses services and pay in return to specific merchant so I want merchant's email address to store in database .

Answer (score 0):

Just use below Code

Create a POPup with a textfield and Ask for Email ID.

```
-(IBAction)savemarchentID:(id)sender
{
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init] ;
payment.recipient = emailfield.text;

//if you want to save in data base then call the method here

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to authenticate merchant email address ,whether it is his paypal email Id or its fake. Like we do in facebook while login and we get dictionary in response having email address and other fields.

Comment: Add this comment in your Question may be helpfull to Someone to find the answer for you.

Comment: @prateek hello,Can you please share how to get all details after transaction is completed?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search,I found my answer ,there is "GetVerifiedStatus" api provided by paypal which is used to check whether user is having correct paypal email address .